# Google-Apps-Script - convert HH:MM argument to fraction of a day

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, time

I have '12:30' in a cell in my Google sheet. It is passed in as an argument into my function (Google Apps Script) and I want to be able to extract the value 12 and the value 30. I want to then be able to return 0.5+0.0208333 = 0.5208333 to represent the fraction of the day that 12:30 represents.
I have searched and not been able to find a solution to this simple problem.
When I change the format to 'number' on the Google sheet it is passed correctly as a float 0.520833 but that defeats the purpose of being able to allow the user to enter a 'HH:MM' format value on the Google sheet user interface.
Can someone tell me how, specifically within Google Apps Script I can extract the HH and the MM passed in as an 'HH:MM' argument.

Comment: Take a look at the split methid in JavaScript

Comment: Thanks Cooper but... when I use str.split(";") I get the following ERROR popping up on the Google sheet cell:
>> TypeError: Cannot find function split in object
it's as if the function split() and a lot of other normal Javascript functions don't exist within Google Apps Script!  I am baffled by that too as a result!

Comment: Oh so it’s probably being treated as a Date(). So try using those methods.

Comment: Or perhaps toString().

Comment: Thanks Cooper! Just doing a toString() as you suggested and subsequently running string functions allowed me to get the HH and MM as integer values. What you said about toString() was what helped me past the stumbling block and then it was smooth sailing. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

- Select the column(say A:A) in Google sheets and format it as `HH:MM`. This will enable users to enter in `HH:MM` format.
- Use apps-script to change the number format onEdit

#### Sample Script:

```
function onEdit(e){
 if (e.range.columnStart != 1) return; //A:A
 e.range.setNumberFormat('#.######');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not come even close to answering the question I asked.

Comment: @purn How and why?